# How to build these table rates?

Tags: shipping, table-rates

I have to specifiy the following table rates, but I have no idea how the file must look. These are the rules

```
Germany (DE) --> 3.90 EUR, if the order total is > 35 EUR, free shipping
Any other country except Germany --> 7.70 EUR, if the order total is > 50 EUR, free shipping
```

How would I define that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Arnie, please check my answer. It should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using Magento's built in table rate shipping method.

First set the calculation type to 'Price vs. Destination':

[image]

Then upload a CSV file with the following contents:

[image]

Should work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with this extension -> [Owebia](http://www.owebia.com/). 
Note that you have a free version with a limit of 3 sets of conditions.

Try this:

```
{
   "destination_DE": {
      "label": "Germany (DE)",
      "shipto": "DE",
      "fees": "{table {cart.price+tax+discount} in 35.0:3.9, *:0}"
   },
   "destination_NOT_DE": {
      "label": "Any other country except Germany",
      "fees": "{table {cart.price+tax+discount} in 50.0:7.7, *:0}"
   }
}
```

Make sure you activate this box: **Stop to first match**, This will ensure that only one rule will be applied. If the first one is true (DE), the second will never be called.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not really get how to use it. I installed the extensin and it shows up, but I am stuck here. Can you give me a little hint?

Comment: Just updated my answer with a possible solution. Try it please.